# Rename files, based on a list

Tags: windows, powershell, file, batch-file, file-rename

Available methods, AFAIK: creating a *.bat file on Windows 7 that does the job. Cannot install any other programs.

Let's say we have a folder that contains some files. I have a list where each of those files, depending on their filename, are associated with an ID.

Now I need to copy those files, based on that list, to somewhere with the associated ID as the filename.

Example:

Files in a folder:

```
10.txt
11.txt
12.txt
```

The list:

```
10 83
11 49
12 94
```

The result should be:

```
10.txt → 83.txt
11.txt → 49.txt
12.txt → 94.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question does not specify if you want it for all files, specific files, or whether your list file will also contain the extension of files, so I will use your examples only:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%i in (list.txt) do (
   if exist "%%i.txt" %%j copy /Y "%%i.txt" "%%j.txt"

)
```

You might want to add `/Y` to suppress prompting of overwriting files. If however you don't want to overwrite and perhaps at a later stage the content of the source files might need appending to the existing new files, then you can check existence of target file then append:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%i in (list.txt) do (
   if exist "%%i.txt" if not exist "%%j.txt copy "%%i.txt" "%%j.txt"
   if exist "%%j.txt" type "%%i.txt">>"%%j.txt"
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have already tried to do it myself but didnt get it after a few hours of Research. Now with your example / solution I get it!